How to split bigint into 32 bit chunks and recombine them?
How do I split a large bigint into a 32 bit number array? I also need to recombine them to the bigint again.
I have an api that takes an array of max 32 bit integers and returns an array of max 32 bit integers. But I have a large bigint number that I need to pass into and receive back from this api.
How do I do the splitting and recombining?



function bigintTo32BitArray(bigint) {
    const result = [];
    const mask = BigInt(0xFFFFFFFF); // 32-bit mask
    while (bigint > 0) {
        result.push(Number(bigint & mask)); // Extract the lowest 32 bits and convert to Number
        bigint >>= 32n; // Shift right by 32 bits
    }
    return result;
}

const bigNumber = 123456789123456789178978978987978978978923434534534534534556789n;
const chunks = bigintTo32BitArray(bigNumber);
console.log(chunks);

function arrayToBigInt(array) {
    let result = 0n;
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        result = (result << 32n) + BigInt(array[i]);
    }
    return result;
}

const out = arrayToBigInt(chunks);
console.log(out, out === bigNumber);




are you sure you want the values in the array to be little-endian? oh, and const arrayToBigInt = (array) => array.reduceRight((r, i) => (r << 32n) + BigInt(i), 0n); :p

The api I'm working against doesn't care. I'd love to see another answer with big endian if anybody else needs it.

Big endian you'd just use .unshift instead of .push and .reduce instead of .reduceRight

This doesn't work on -1n
